# Word for somebody who wants others to bootlick them

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

A bootlicker is somebody who tries to curry favour with somebody by flattery/acting friendly with them.

Is there a word for somebody who wants others to booklick him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common phrase used:

> susceptible to flattery

A possible idiom:

> compliment fisher / fishing for compliments

And the rather long phrase (and my preferred choice):

> likes to have his ego stroked

Comment: Although it's not a single word, I think this fits the meaning of what I want best.

Comment: Thanks! :)  Fortunately or unfortunately, a great many of these phrases come into existence because there is no single good word to describe the thing in question.  It's much easier instead to "paint the picture".

Answer (score 1):

You could call him a **martinet**

This is someone who strictly requires exact compliance with his orders.

http://i.word.com/idictionary/martinet

Or call him a **diva** or a **prima donna**.  (The fact that these are female terms may make them seem especially pejorative if applied to a man.)

Answer (score 0):

> Manager

"Brown-nosing" or "arse-licking" are also used, in some countries far more prevalently that "boot-licking".

Answer (score 0):

I always liked the term ***"despot"***. While, technically it describes someone with the "right" to absolute power, it conjures slimy images of sociopathic rule, (to me) and therefore, makes a nice insult.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like a *narcissist* or an *egotist*?
These are more like people who want to be praised all the time.

Comment: Narcissism is admiring yourself too much, and egoism is having the feeling that you're superior to others, neither of these terms has the connotation of 'expecting praise from other.'